# ERROR: unrecognised command `sh`, or `python`, or `bash` while all can be executed inside the image

Tags: bash, docker, docker-compose, flagsmith

I want to run a script after a docker image has been initialized. The image in question is a node:16 with python and other stuff

https://github.com/Flagsmith/flagsmith/blob/main/Dockerfile

Anyway, if I run the image without commands or entry-point it does start successfully. If I login using `docker exec -it ###### /bin/bas` I can then run either `sh`, `bash` or even `python`

However having:

```
  flagsmith:
      image: flagsmith/flagsmith:latest
      environment:
          # skipping for readibility
      ports:
          - "9000:8000"
      depends_on:
          - flotto-postgres
      links:
          - flotto-postgres
      volumes: ['./init_flagsmith.py:/init_flagsmith.py', './init_flagsmith.sh:/init_flagsmith.sh']
      command: /bin/bash '/init_flagsmith.sh'  # <-------- THIS GUY IS NOT WORKING
```

it does not run, and the returned error is 0 with this message (depending on the tool I run on `init_flagsmith.sh` :

> ERROR: unrecognised command '/bin/bash'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the end of the Dockerfile you link to, it specifies

```bash
ENTRYPOINT ["./scripts/run-docker.sh"]
CMD ["migrate-and-serve"]
```

In the Compose file, the `command:` overrides the Dockerfile `CMD`, but it still is [passed as arguments to the `ENTRYPOINT`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#understand-how-cmd-and-entrypoint-interact).  Looking at the [`run-docker.sh`](https://github.com/Flagsmith/flagsmith/blob/main/api/scripts/run-docker.sh) script, it does not accept a normal shell command as its arguments, but rather one of a specific set of command keywords (`migrate`, `serve`, ...).

You could in principle work around this by replacing `command:` with `entrypoint:` in your Compose file.  However, you'll still run into the problem that a container only runs one process, and so your setup script runs *instead of* the normal container process.

What you might do instead is set up your initialization script to run the main entrypoint script when it finishes.

```bash
#!/bin/sh
# init_flagsmith.sh

...

# at the very end
exec ./scripts/run-docker.sh "$@"
```

I also might package this up into an image, rather than injecting the files using `volumes:`.  You can create an image `FROM` any base image you want to extend it.

```bash
# Dockerfile
FROM flagsmith/flagsmith:latest
COPY init_flagsmith.sh init_flagsmith.py ./
ENTRYPOINT ["./init_flagsmith.sh"]  # must be JSON-array syntax
CMD ["migrate-and-serve"]           # must repeat from the base image
                                    # if changing ENTRYPOINT
```

Then you can remove these options from the Compose setup (along with the obsolete `links:`)

```yaml
  flagsmith:
      build: .
      environment:
          # skipping for readibility
      ports:
          - "9000:8000"
      depends_on:
          - flotto-postgres
      # but no volumes:, command:, or entrypoint:
```

Comment: amazing. I got the points I guess about `CMD`, `ENTRYPOINT` and the order of execution. Thanks a lot for the very complete answer!